# Exact Differential Equations of Order n?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A second order ode $Py'' + Qy' + Ry = 0$ is exact if

$$(Ay' + By)' = Ay'' + (A' + B)y' + B'y = Py'' + Qy' + Ry = 0$$

How can one cast the analysis of this question in terms of exact differential equations?

In other words, could somebody explain this interesting quote:

> The derivation of the conditions of exact integrability of an ordinary
> differential equation of the nth. order (or of a differential expression involving
> derivatives of a single dependent variable with regard to a single independent
> variable) is sometimes made to depend upon the theory of integration of an
> expression, exact in the sense of the foregoing chapter. As however the
> connection is not immediate and this method is not the principal method, it
> will be sufficient here to give the following references to some of the writers
> on the subject, in whose memoirs references to Euler, Lagrange, Lexell, and
> Condorcet, will be found in ...
> [Forsyth - Page 33](http://books.google.ie/books?id=ci-9g2oq29EC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Thanks!